# how add class in containers

Tags: html

i make this dynamic side menu and put this coad after this genrate this `<div class="menu-side-menu-container">` but i want to  add class in this containers

my header.php

```
<!-- Navigation Menu -->
<div class="sidenav">
  <div class="pull-right col-sm-6">
    <a class="sidebar-logo" href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.jpg"/></a>
    <div class="menu-sidebar">

        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'side_menu' ) ) : ?>


                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'side_menu' ); ?>


                 <?php endif; ?>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

output look like this

```
    <div class="menu-sidebar">
<div class="menu-side-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-side-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-3136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-3136">
<li id="menu-item-3137" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-3137">
<li id="menu-item-3138" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-3138">
<li id="menu-item-3139" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-3139">
<li id="menu-item-3140" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-3140">
<li id="menu-item-3141" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3141">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

i want to this class ( class="menu-sidebar") add to in container class ........because my css is running in this class (class="menu-sidebar") and this container class change to my css display....

how could b  possible this changes............if yes so please share and solve this probleam

Comment: How do you create this menu? Please edit the question and complete it with useful information.

Comment: i m update my question plz check

Comment: This is not "How you create", this is "How you display". Is your menu a widget?

Comment: this is widget custom menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand using rigid widgets having the ability to edit the theme. So, I call attention to the `wp_nav_menu()` for flexibility improvement.

`functions.php`:

```
<?php

// register menu in `side_menu`
register_nav_menu( 'side_menu', __( 'Sidebar', 'theme-slug' ) );
```

Now you can build your own menu under Appearance -> Menus.

Use `wp_nav_menu()` function to display your menu in the `header.php`:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'side_menu',
    'menu'            => 'side_menu',
    // here goes the container
    'container'       => 'div',
    // here goes the container classes
    'container_class' => 'menu-side-menu-container menu-sidebar',
    // more arguments if different fron default
    // See the link at the end
);

wp_nav_menu($args);
```

For more information see:

- [register_nav_menu()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu)
- [wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)
- [nav_menu_css_class filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class)

Comment: @ max yudin................................i got it..............thanks